# C# how to split and get one specifiq answer line from adb

Tags: c#, adb

**my code**

```
text = ExecADB(string_, "-s " + array[0] + "shell cat /proc/cpuinfo");
TracerWrite("Cpu: ", Color.White); 
TracerWriteLine(text.Trim(), Color.SeaGreen);
```

this is full output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdgyD.png)

***How to split just:***

Hardware : Qualcomm Technologies, Inc MSM8937

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead [edit] your question to include any text you want to show as text. Also, it's a bit hard to understand what you want. Can you try to describe a state in your code that you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the substring you're looking for is always followed by a specific string (like the newline character or `"Revision"`), we can use [`IndexOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=net-7.0) to get the starting index of a substring within a string (using `"Hardware"` as the start string to search for), and [`Substring`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-7.0) to get the actual string. To get the length of the string we're looking for, we can get the index of the string we know always follows it and subtract that from our starting index:

```
var text = "CPU revision: 4\r\nHardware: Qualcomm Technologies\r\nRevision: 8300";
var hardware = string.Empty;

// Find the indices of the start and end of the string we want
var startOfString = "Hardware";
var endOfString = Environment.NewLine;  // Or possibly "Revision"

var startIndex = text.IndexOf(startOfString);
if (startIndex > -1)
{
    var endIndex = text.IndexOf(endOfString, startIndex + startOfString.Length);

    if (endIndex < 0) hardware = text.Substring(startIndex);
    else hardware = text.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex).TrimEnd();
}

// Output the string we were searching for
Console.WriteLine(hardware);

Console.Write("\n\nDone. Press any key to exit...");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: please check https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdgyD.png

Comment: @R3M0T3smith I saw that, which is why I chose `"Hardware"` as the start of the string and `Environment.NewLine;  // Or possibly "Revision"` as the string that follows the substring we're trying to capture. Please add more details to your comment - is something not working?